# Confusion understanding a transducer manual for wiring

Tags: transducer

In the [Setra Model 270](https://www.setra.com/hubfs/Product_Operating_Instructions/Setra_Model_270_Operating_Instructions.pdf) transducer manual the following instructions are given:

[image]

Do they mean that the excitation negative terminal should be separate with the output signal's ground? And the shield is connected to the excitation negative terminal? Is my way of wiring correct below?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transducer of this type works best with a differential input amplifier and should preferably not be used with a single-ended input as your diagram implies. Additionally, because the case is likely to be grounded, you have possibly  contravened the first requirement - that of NOT applying multiple grounds i.e. your output port is shown with a ground symbol.

If your excitation power supply is fully isolated from ground you can connect the output port negative terminal to ground. However, it will still be preferable to use a differential input if the cable-run can pick-up noise. See this: -

> Best shielding against noise will be obtained by connecting the shield
>   and negative excitation leads.

And this implies to me that you use a grounded excitation power supply and differential (balanced) input measurement amplifier.

Comment: I use scope for now to see output. But when I common the negative excitation terminal and output signal ground the transducer does not respond anything to pressure. When I separate the excitation negative and output signal ground I get response. This is strange I dont know why.

Comment: I use 24V sinlge power supply not bipolar supply for the excitation.

Comment: Could you also if possible provide a diagram what you meant would be easier to follow and try. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are wanting to see on the diagram? Are you confused by the diagrams in the data sheet for the device? Option 1 (sheet 2) is the best idea. Option 2 requires multiple isolated power supplies and this is harder to implement and is weaker in terms of noise because the output terminal is grounded and this is not preferred. Option 3 can be implemented with a differential input with signal multiplexing. Not sure what a diagram will give you.

Comment: I see mate, its just I dont know why the transducer does not work when I connect  -Exc and -out together. The datasheet says there must be one ground but when I ground -Exc and -out it doesnt work. I thought I misunderstood the written thing.

Comment: You are grounding at two points and two points should not be grounded because they are not internally at the same electrical connection. You can ground at point A or at point B but not both - read the first quote in your question.

Comment: Yes I forgot to chose.